# How to update an element in array using yq by not using the index, but rather some contextual info, like a name

Tags: kubernetes, yq

this is the input

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: kube-vip
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
    - args:
        - start
      env:
        - name: vip_arp
          value: "true"
        - name: vip_leaderelection
          value: "true"
        - name: vip_address
          value: 
        - name: vip_interface
          value: eth0
        - name: vip_leaseduration
          value: "15"
        - name: vip_renewdeadline
          value: "10"
        - name: vip_retryperiod
          value: "2"
      image: ghcr.io/kube-vip/kube-vip:v0.3.5
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      name: kube-vip
      resources: {}
      securityContext:
        capabilities:
          add:
            - NET_ADMIN
            - SYS_TIME
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
          name: kubeconfig
  hostNetwork: true
  volumes:
    - hostPath:
        path: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
        type: FileOrCreate
      name: kubeconfig
status: {}
```

and I'd like to update the file and get the output. I can do that by using:

```
cat $file | yq e '.spec.containers[].env[2].value="sdf"'
```

But that assumes the index of `vip_address` env var will be always `2`. Is it possible to have something like this

```
yq e '. | select(.spec.containers[].env[].name=="vip_address") | .value="sdf"'
```

that will actually work and update the `value` of `vip_address`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it can be done with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq). You need to drop down to the last level list item `env` and then use the update-select operator `|=`

```bash
yq '.spec.containers[].env |= map(select(.name=="vip_address").value="sdf")' yaml
```

Also note that since 4.18.1, [yq's `eval/e`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1) command is the default command and no longer needs to be specified.

---

If you want to double-quote the `.value` field, update the [style](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/style#update-and-set-style-of-a-particular-node-using-path-variables) for the particular node to double i.e.

```bash
yq '.spec.containers[].env |= map(select(.name=="vip_address").value="sdf" | .value style="double")' yaml
```